# ES6 .forEach method not looping array?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am having some trouble with my `.forEach` loop. Here is my current code:

```
let isPangram = (phrase) => {
  let alphabet = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];
  alphabet.forEach(function(letter) {
    if (phrase.toLowerCase().includes(letter)) {
      alphabet.splice(alphabet.indexOf(letter), 1);
    }
    debugger;
  });
  if (alphabet.length === 0) {
    return true;
  }
  else if (alphabet.length > 0) {
    return false;
  }
};
```

When I run this in the console with the `debugger`, it seems to skip over some letters like `b` and `c`. Can anyone tell me what's going on here?

Comment: This is a fun golf exercise: `let isPangram = phrase => new Set(phrase.toLowerCase().match(/[a-z]/g)).size === 26;` :D

Comment: `return alphabet.every(letter => phrase.toLowerCase().includes(letter));` https://jsfiddle.net/a5w5db66/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be deleting the current element from the array when iterating with `.forEach()`.  When you remove with `.splice()`, it removes an element and the elements in the array afterwards move down a slot and then the next step of the iteration misses the element that just moved into the current iteration slot.

A safer way to do this would be to use a traditional `for` loop and iterate backwards from end to front.  Then, any changes you make to the array will be outside of what you are iterating.  Of course, there's probably just a better overall way to write this without splicing at all.  Personally, I'd probably use a `Set` object to keep track of all used letters and see if I end up with all 26 in the end.

From the [MDN page for `.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach): ***"If elements that are already visited are removed (e.g. using shift()) during the iteration, later elements will be skipped - see example below."***

Also, `forEach()` is not something that is new to ES6, it has been present since ES5.

---

Here's a non-deletion way using some ES6 features to test for a pangram:

```js
const allCharsSet = new Set("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");

function isPangram(phrase) {
    let foundLetters = new Set();
    for (let ch of phrase) {
     ch = ch.toLowerCase();
        if (allCharsSet.has(ch)) {
         foundLetters.add(ch);
        }
    }
    return foundLetters.size === allCharsSet.size;
}

console.log(isPangram("The five boxing wizards jump quickly."));
console.log(isPangram("Many-wived Jack laughs at probes of sex quiz."));
console.log(isPangram("Playing jazz vibe chords quickly excites my wife."));
console.log(isPangram("some other phrase"));
```

Comment: Thank you! that makes a lot of sense. I ended up creating a new array called `matches` and whenever I got a match I pushed the letter into the new array and that worked. Thanks again!

Comment: @GeorgeLi - Since you mentioned ES6, I've added an ES6 way of doing this that does not have to delete things from an array.

Comment: @GeorgeLi - Since it looks like you may be new here, if this has answered your question, then you can indicate that to the community by clicking the green checkmark to the left of the answer.  This will also earn you some reputation points which can lead to earning more privileges on the site.

Comment: Great explanation of the problem, but the solution could be much simpler since there's a method for that: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every

Comment: @pawel - If you think it's a lot simpler and just as efficient with `.every()` , then please post your own answer that implements the `isPangram()` function using it.

Comment: @jfriend00 added as a comment since I think your answer is great. OP problem is not about codegolfing an alternative solution but understanding why forEach doesn't work as expected. I just think changing `.forEach` to `.every` is a much smaller leap since both are array methods that iterate over the collection, just for different purposes.